# Trying to get a website running on an ec2 instance

Tags: reactjs, amazon-ec2, web-hosting

I am trying to get a simple react/falcon website running on an ec2 instance but i am having some trouble. I suspect the issue is in pointing the public facing url for the instance to a landing/home page for the website but i am not entirely sure.

I have configured inbound rules for the instance to allow all incoming http and https traffic, so i do not believe it is a permissions issue.

I feel like I need to add something to package.json to get it work.

When i run npm start the following outputs:

Compiled successfully!
You can now view sapie-fe in the browser.
Local:            http://localhost:3000/
On Your Network:  http://172.31.26.109:3000/

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.
When i visit http://172.31.26.109:3000/ in my browser nothing happens/loads though. package.json looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "sapie-fe",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "homepage": ".",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
         "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^1.31.0",
         "axios": "0.17.1",
         "classnames": "^2.2.5",
         "object-path": "^0.11.4",
         "react": "^16.2.0",
         "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
         "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
         "react-rebind": "^0.1.9",
         "react-router": "^4.2.0",
         "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.24.4",
         "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
         "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
         "react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",
         "stripe": "^5.4.0"
    },
   "scripts": {
         "start": "react-scripts start",
         "build": "react-scripts build",
         "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
         "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
   "devDependencies": {}
}
```

I think I should add something in here to get it work but am not sure. npm install yields the following:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN react-lorem-component@0.12.2 requires a peer of react@15.x but none was installed.
```

These seem like they could be clues, but are just warnings and on their face seem unrelated to the site not being accesible to me at the public facing url.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: You can ignore the npm WARN logs, you're right. They are unrelated. I would check on the ports you're exposing on your AWS VPC. Have you mapped port 80 to port 3000?

Comment: are you using private ip or public ip?

Answer (score 1):

had to open port 3000 to all incoming connections and it worked. doh!